# SOAP for different versions of same functionality is not working

Tags: java, soap, wsdl

I have two different WSDL's for same process. First one is giving three packages on wsimport while seconds one is giving two packages on wsimport. I think both of the wsdl are from different versions but I am sure that both have same functionality.
The first one with three packages is working fine for me but second one is giving error i. e  [SOAP error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yeqH5.jpg) given in image. I have searched and worked every possibility  but still I am standing at the same issue. Do anyone know what will be the working solution ?

First wsdl

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
- <!--  Published by JAX-WS RI (http://jax-ws.java.net). RI's version is JAX-WS RI 2.3.0-b170407.2038 svn-revision#2eaca54d17a59d265c6fe886b7fd0027836c766c. 
  --> 
- <wsdl:definitions xmlns:tns="http://ouaf.oracle.com/webservices/c1/C1-AccountMail" xmlns:ouaf="http://ouaf.oracle.com/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" name="C1-AccountMail" targetNamespace="http://ouaf.oracle.com/webservices/c1/C1-AccountMail" xmlns:wsp="http://www.w3.org/ns/ws-policy" xmlns:wssutil="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
  <wsp:UsingPolicy wssutil:Required="true" /> 
  <wsdl:documentation>C1-AccountMail version 1: Retrieve an Account's Mailing Address</wsdl:documentation> 
- <wsdl:types>
- <xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ouaf="http://ouaf.oracle.com/" targetNamespace="http://ouaf.oracle.com/" elementFormDefault="unqualified">
- <xsd:element name="Fault">
- <xsd:complexType>
- <xsd:all>
  <xsd:element name="ResponseStatus" type="xsd:string" /> 
  <xsd:element name="ResponseCode" type="xsd:int" /> 
  <xsd:element name="ResponseText" type="xsd:string" /> 
- <xsd:element name="ResponseData" minOccurs="0">
- <xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:attribute name="parm1" type="xsd:string" /> 
  <xsd:attribute name="parm2" type="xsd:string" /> 
  <xsd:attribute name="parm3" type="xsd:string" /> 
  <xsd:attribute name="parm4" type="xsd:string" /> 
  <xsd:attribute name="parm5" type="xsd:string" /> 
  <xsd:attribute name="parm6" type="xsd:string" /> 
  <xsd:attribute name="parm7" type="xsd:string" /> 
  <xsd:attribute name="parm8" type="xsd:string" /> 
  <xsd:attribute name="parm9" type="xsd:string" /> 
  <xsd:attribute name="text" type="xsd:string" /> 
  <xsd:attribute name="category" type="xsd:string" /> 
  <xsd:attribute name="numParm" type="xsd:int" /> 
  <xsd:attribute name="number" type="xsd:int" /> 
  </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
- <xsd:element name="ServerMessage" minOccurs="0">
- <xsd:complexType>
- <xsd:all>
  <xsd:element name="Category" type="xsd:string" /> 
  <xsd:element name="Number" type="xsd:string" /> 
  <xsd:element name="CallSequence" type="xsd:string" /> 
  <xsd:element name="ProgramName" type="xsd:string" /> 
  <xsd:element name="Text" type="xsd:string" /> 
  <xsd:element name="Description" type="xsd:string" /> 
  <xsd:element name="Table" type="xsd:string" /> 
  <xsd:element name="Field" type="xsd:string" /> 
  </xsd:all>
  </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
  </xsd:all>
  </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
- <xsd:simpleType name="money">
  <xsd:restriction base="xsd:decimal" /> 
  </xsd:simpleType>
- <xsd:simpleType name="listAction">
- <xsd:restriction base="xsd:token">
  <xsd:enumeration value="delete" /> 
  <xsd:enumeration value="add" /> 
  <xsd:enumeration value="update" /> 
  </xsd:restriction>
  </xsd:simpleType>
  </xsd:schema>
- <xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ouaf="http://ouaf.oracle.com/" targetNamespace="http://ouaf.oracle.com/webservices/c1/C1-AccountMail" elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xsd:import namespace="http://ouaf.oracle.com/" /> 
- <xsd:element name="C1-AccountMail">
- <xsd:complexType>
- <xsd:sequence>
- <xsd:element name="accountId" minOccurs="0">
- <xsd:simpleType>
- <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
  <xsd:maxLength value="65536" /> 
  </xsd:restriction>
  </xsd:simpleType>
  </xsd:element>
- <xsd:element name="results" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
- <xsd:complexType>
- <xsd:sequence>
- <xsd:element name="premise" minOccurs="0">
- <xsd:simpleType>
- <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
  <xsd:maxLength value="4000" /> 
  </xsd:restriction>
  </xsd:simpleType>
  </xsd:element>
- <xsd:element name="premiseInfo" minOccurs="0">
- <xsd:simpleType>
- <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
  <xsd:maxLength value="4000" /> 
  </xsd:restriction>
  </xsd:simpleType>
  </xsd:element>
  </xsd:sequence>
  <xsd:attribute name="action" type="ouaf:listAction" /> 
  </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
  </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
  </xsd:schema>
  </wsdl:types>
- <!--  wsdl:message elements describe potential transactions --> 
- <!--  request for operation C1-AccountMail --> 
- <wsdl:message name="C1-AccountMailRequest">
  <wsdl:part name="body" element="tns:C1-AccountMail" /> 
  </wsdl:message>
- <!--  response for operation C1-AccountMail --> 
- <wsdl:message name="C1-AccountMailResponse">
  <wsdl:part name="body" element="tns:C1-AccountMail" /> 
  </wsdl:message>
- <!--  fault type --> 
- <wsdl:message name="Fault">
  <wsdl:part name="fault" element="ouaf:Fault" /> 
  </wsdl:message>
- <!--  wsdl:portType describes messages in an operation --> 
- <wsdl:portType name="C1-AccountMailPortType">
  <wsdl:documentation>C1-AccountMail version 1: Retrieve an Account's Mailing Address</wsdl:documentation> 
- <wsdl:operation name="C1-AccountMail">
  <wsdl:input message="tns:C1-AccountMailRequest" /> 
  <wsdl:output message="tns:C1-AccountMailResponse" /> 
  <wsdl:fault name="fault" message="tns:Fault" /> 
  </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
- <!--  wsdl:binding states a serialization protocol for this service --> 
- <wsdl:binding name="C1-AccountMailSoapBinding" type="tns:C1-AccountMailPortType">
  <wsp:PolicyReference URI="policy:Wssp1.2-2007-Https-BasicAuth.xml" /> 
- <!-- leverage off soap:binding document style @@@(no wsdl:foo pointing at
    the soap binding) --> 
<soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" /> 
- <!-- semi-opaque container of network transport details classed by
      soap:binding above @@@ --> 
- <wsdl:operation name="C1-AccountMail">
- <!--  again bind to SOAP? @@@ --> 
  <soap:operation soapAction="http://10.1.5.86:6500/webservices/C1-AccountMail#C1-AccountMail" /> 
- <!-- further specify that the messages in the wsdl:operation
            "C1-AccountMail" use SOAP? @@@ --> 
- <wsdl:input>
  <soap:body use="literal" /> 
  </wsdl:input>
+ <wsdl:output>
  <soap:body use="literal" /> 
  </wsdl:output>
- <wsdl:fault name="fault">
  <soap:fault name="fault" use="literal" /> 
  </wsdl:fault>
  </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
- <!--  wsdl:service names a new service "C1-AccountMailService" --> 
+ <wsdl:service name="C1-AccountMailService">
  <wsdl:documentation>C1-AccountMail version 1: Retrieve an Account's Mailing Address</wsdl:documentation> 
- <!--  connect it to the binding "C1-AccountMailSoapBinding" above --> 
- <wsdl:port name="C1-AccountMailPort" binding="tns:C1-AccountMailSoapBinding">
- <!--  give the binding a network address --> 
  <soap:address location="http://10.1.5.86:6500/ouaf/webservices/C1-AccountMail" /> 
  </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
  </wsdl:definitions>
```

Second WSDL

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<!--  Published by JAX-WS RI (http://jax-ws.java.net). RI's version is JAX-WS RI 2.3.0-b170407.2038 svn-revision#2eaca54d17a59d265c6fe886b7fd0027836c766c.  -->
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:tns="http://ouaf.oracle.com/webservices/c1/C1-AccountMail" xmlns:ouaf="http://ouaf.oracle.com/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:wsp="http://www.w3.org/ns/ws-policy" xmlns:wssutil="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" name="C1-AccountMail" targetNamespace="http://ouaf.oracle.com/webservices/c1/C1-AccountMail">
<wsp:UsingPolicy wssutil:Required="true"/>
<wsdl:documentation>C1-AccountMail version 1: Retrieve an Account's Mailing Address</wsdl:documentation>
<wsdl:types>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ouaf="http://ouaf.oracle.com/" targetNamespace="http://ouaf.oracle.com/" elementFormDefault="unqualified">
<xsd:element name="Fault">
<xsd:complexType>
<xsd:all>
<xsd:element name="ResponseStatus" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element name="ResponseCode" type="xsd:int"/>
<xsd:element name="ResponseText" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element name="ResponseData" minOccurs="0">
<xsd:complexType>
<xsd:attribute name="parm1" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:attribute name="parm2" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:attribute name="parm3" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:attribute name="parm4" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:attribute name="parm5" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:attribute name="parm6" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:attribute name="parm7" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:attribute name="parm8" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:attribute name="parm9" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:attribute name="text" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:attribute name="category" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:attribute name="numParm" type="xsd:int"/>
<xsd:attribute name="number" type="xsd:int"/>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="ServerMessage" minOccurs="0">
<xsd:complexType>
<xsd:all>
<xsd:element name="Category" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element name="Number" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element name="CallSequence" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element name="ProgramName" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element name="Text" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element name="Description" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element name="Table" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element name="Field" type="xsd:string"/>
</xsd:all>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
</xsd:all>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:simpleType name="money">
<xsd:restriction base="xsd:decimal"/>
</xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:simpleType name="listAction">
<xsd:restriction base="xsd:token">
<xsd:enumeration value="delete"/>
<xsd:enumeration value="add"/>
<xsd:enumeration value="update"/>
</xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
</xsd:schema>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ouaf="http://ouaf.oracle.com/" targetNamespace="http://ouaf.oracle.com/webservices/c1/C1-AccountMail" elementFormDefault="qualified">
<xsd:import namespace="http://ouaf.oracle.com/"/>
<xsd:element name="C1-AccountMail">
<xsd:complexType>
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element name="accountId" minOccurs="0">
<xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
<xsd:maxLength value="65536"/>
</xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="results" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
<xsd:complexType>
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element name="premise" minOccurs="0">
<xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
<xsd:maxLength value="4000"/>
</xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="premiseInfo" minOccurs="0">
<xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
<xsd:maxLength value="4000"/>
</xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
</xsd:element>
</xsd:sequence>
<xsd:attribute name="action" type="ouaf:listAction"/>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
</wsdl:types>
<!--  wsdl:message elements describe potential transactions  -->
<!--  request for operation C1-AccountMail  -->
<wsdl:message name="C1-AccountMailRequest">
<wsdl:part name="body" element="tns:C1-AccountMail"/>
</wsdl:message>
<!--  response for operation C1-AccountMail  -->
<wsdl:message name="C1-AccountMailResponse">
<wsdl:part name="body" element="tns:C1-AccountMail"/>
</wsdl:message>
<!--  fault type  -->
<wsdl:message name="Fault">
<wsdl:part name="fault" element="ouaf:Fault"/>
</wsdl:message>
<!--  wsdl:portType describes messages in an operation  -->
<wsdl:portType name="C1-AccountMailPortType">
<wsdl:documentation>C1-AccountMail version 1: Retrieve an Account's Mailing Address</wsdl:documentation>
<wsdl:operation name="C1-AccountMail">
<wsdl:input message="tns:C1-AccountMailRequest"/>
<wsdl:output message="tns:C1-AccountMailResponse"/>
<wsdl:fault name="fault" message="tns:Fault"/>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<!--  wsdl:binding states a serialization protocol for this service  -->
<wsdl:binding name="C1-AccountMailSoapBinding" type="tns:C1-AccountMailPortType">
<wsp:PolicyReference URI="policy:Wssp1.2-2007-Https-BasicAuth.xml"/>
<!--  leverage off soap:binding document style @@@(no wsdl:foo pointing at
         the soap binding)  -->
<soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<!--  semi-opaque container of network transport details classed by
         soap:binding above @@@  -->
<wsdl:operation name="C1-AccountMail">
<!--  again bind to SOAP? @@@  -->
<soap:operation soapAction="http://CIS17/webservices/C1-AccountMail#C1-AccountMail"/>
<!--  further specify that the messages in the wsdl:operation
           "C1-AccountMail" use SOAP? @@@  -->
<wsdl:input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
<wsdl:fault name="fault">
<soap:fault name="fault" use="literal"/>
</wsdl:fault>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<!--  wsdl:service names a new service "C1-AccountMailService"  -->
<wsdl:service name="C1-AccountMailService">
<wsdl:documentation>C1-AccountMail version 1: Retrieve an Account's Mailing Address</wsdl:documentation>
<!--  connect it to the binding "C1-AccountMailSoapBinding" above  -->
<wsdl:port name="C1-AccountMailPort" binding="tns:C1-AccountMailSoapBinding">
<!--  give the binding a network address  -->
<soap:address location="http://10.1.5.95:6500/ouaf/webservices/C1-AccountMail"/>
</wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Comment: The second wsdl is incorrect. You have a namespace problem. you've specified that the targetnamespace for the wsdl has an ip address ending at 95 while the schema definition part ends on 86. The 86 namespace is prefixed as tns. When you defined ```<wsdl:input message="tns:NewOperationRequest"/>``` the parser looks for an message named NewOperationRequest with the 86 namespace but you defined the message with the 95 namespace. change the wsdl targetnamespace to 86 will solve the incorrect wsdl problem.

Comment: Sorry,  it was my lack during posting query,  I have updated that but still getting same error.